# How add DropDownList without binding to ViewData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I do:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ddBrand", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Brands, new {onchange = "JavaScript:Act()"})
```

But when I press submit it needs the field "ddBrand" in View Model.

How can I add DropDownList to View without binding to ViewData? (without adding field "ddBrand" in View Model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply generate the HTML. You can create the `option`s in a for loop. You can give different name to the `id` and `name` attributes.

```
<select id="ddBrand" name="ddBrand">
  <option value="value">Text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've create little funtion to do it, it returns string. When I do @MyDropDownList.Create("ddType", "JavaScript:DisplayTextType()", ViewBag.VehicleTypes) it's insert it as text (replace "<" to &lt;). How can I fix it?

Comment: @Kak your `Create` method should return a `MvcHtmlString` not a `string`. Because Razor syntax encodes ordinary strings.